# How to split following string which has an array inside

Tags: java, split

String to split: `java[d]program`

Expected output: `java and program`

but got output: `java[ and ]program`

I used following code:

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    String [] test;
    String text = "java[d]program";
    test=text.split("[d]");
    System.out.println(""+test[0]);
    System.out.println(""+test[1]);
}
```

Any help?

Comment: I hope you meant `test=text.split("[d]");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 
        String [] test; String text = "java[d]program";    
        test=text.split("\\[d\\]");    
        System.out.println(""+test[0]);    
        System.out.println(""+test[1]); 
    }
```

**Output:**

```
java
program
```

Comment: Now how different is that from [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9274449/343955)?

Comment: @adarshr: when i post my answer your answer also there, just in a few minutes. Btw my answer is no different from yours, you can see that.

Answer (score 4):

You should escape `[` and `]`.

```
split("\\[d\\]");
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.split()` uses regular expressions so it should be something like this (if I understand what you want):

```
test = text.split("\\[.*\\]");
```